# Average all frames of video in an image

Tags: video, average, reinforcement-learning

I am currently learning reinforcement learning and I record how my agent plays overnight to later see what it's been up to.

The environment is static, so the only think changing is agent's and enemies' position. I think it would be a lot informative and quicker for me if I could just average out all frames and see the overall pattern of movement for agent.

I think ffmpeg might be good for this task, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Found a tool that does exactly that!

https://github.com/dohliam/video-averaging